# How to have only one consumer handle a long running task at a given point?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architectural-patterns, message-queue, queueing

I need to design an application which makes requests to an external API. External API has a hierarchy of entities: `User` which contains `ListOfItems`s which contain `Items`. I need to get data on all `Item`s for all `User`s. Within a `ListOfItems` requests per `Item` can be concurrent/parallel but only one `ListOfItems` can be requested at a time, due to external API limitations (`ListOfItems` can only be accessed via a token and a token for only one `ListOfItems` is issued within a given `User`). There will be around 1000 `User`s max.

I need to get this data ideally once an hour but in reality this takes longer because the amount of `User`s and `Item`s is quite large. I already have the code for the method `processUser`:

```
processUser(user) {
  List<ListOfItems> lists = getListsPerUser(user);
  List<Items> items;
  for (list in lists) {
    items = getItemsPerListConcurrently(list);
    processItems(items);
  }
}
```

Currently, I have a cron job which runs immediately after the previous job finished. The job has a thread executor which creates `N` threads and each thread runs `processUser` inside a Kubernetes pod. So `User`s and `Item`s are processed in parallel but `ListOfItems` are processed serially. I'd like to scale the solution to multiple pods but this requires to make sure that at any given time same `ListOfItems` is not processed by different pods because the token to access user data can only be used for one `ListOfItems` at a time (if 2 pods process the same `ListOfItems` then we have a problem).

Initially, I thought to go with a message queue as a solution and having each consumer process some `User` because there's already a method `processUser` and this feature needs to be delivered ASAP. So a message would contain a `User` id. The problem is that it can take hours to process a `User`. As far as I know many message queues have some interval to acknowledge that a message was processed, if the interval has passed without acknowledgement then the message may be returned to the broker (Kafka has this I think, AWS SQS definitely has this). This means that a message to process `User` may be stuck in the queue for hours potentially even a day because all consumers are busy processing other `User`s. It feels like `processUser` is a long-running task which message queues may not be suited best for.

There're several directions I'm thinking about:

1. Use some kind of queue/list of tasks where each task represents a `User`. Spin up `N` `processUser` instances, then each `processUser` instance pops a `User` from the queue. The pop operation should be atomic so that multiple `processUser` instances don't process same `User`/`ListOfItems`. Maybe I could use Redis `BLPOP` which is atomic? This solution would be the quickest to implement in my opinion because `processUser` code is already written. This is good because the feature needs to be delivered ASAP.
2. Refactor code to use a message queue with ordering guaranteed like Kafka where each message would contain an `Item` id and message key = `ListOfItems` id to prevent more than one consumer processing the same `ListOfItems`. We already have Kafka infrastructure so just refactor `processUser`.
3. Use database synchronization (we use Postgres) so each consumer checks a database table `UsersInProgress` for which `User` is available and process it. One option is to lock the whole table to make sure that multiple `processUser` instances don't grab the same `User` but I think we can just use a transaction where first we check if a `User` is being processed, if not then making a write to the table marking the `User` as being processed. Because writes are atomic we guarantee that only one instance will be able to grab a `User`.

I was wondering if any of the above options sound good taking into consideration that the feature needs to be delivered quickly or maybe there's another option that I didn't think of.

In case option 1 sounds good is Redis/BLPOP really the best solution or there're better solutions?

In case option 3 sounds good will using a transaction to first check if user is processed then mark it as processed work to prevent having multiple instances processing same user?